# How to Get the Region From set of LatLng in google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I m Developing a app  in which user draw a Polygon. i have a set of LatLng. now i want to Show  all the markers that belongs to set of LatLng. all the marker which doesn't belong in that i want to remove it. I have attached a image. How can i achieved that. Thanks In advance.

```
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng cz1 = new LatLng(53.600, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;
    private CameraPosition cameraPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));

        Marker cz = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cz1)
                .title("cz"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
        cameraPosition = arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FreeDrawActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("position", cameraPosition);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
        super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        if (arg2 != null) {
            Draw_Map((ArrayList<LatLng>) arg2.getSerializableExtra("result"));
        }

    }

    public void Draw_Map(ArrayList<LatLng> val) {
        PolygonOptions  rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
        rectOptions.addAll(val);
        rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
        rectOptions.strokeWidth(7);
        rectOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(125, 255, 255, 255));
        Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(rectOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Check wether given latlng belongs to a set of latlng. Then you need to use the PolyUtil library provided by the google developer [Download from here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java). and  use the

```
PolyUtil.containsLocation(LatLng Object, set of lat lng, boolean)
```

this method returns true if given latlng belongs to set of latlngs. other wise false

for ex:-

```
if(PolyUtil.containsLocation(KIEL, val, false)) {
            kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to determine if a point (i.e. "marker") is inside or outside a given polygon drawn by the user. In that case, you'll want to implement this algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon.

Comment: That algorithm will allow you to filter which points are inside the polygon. Then draw those.